# Find the product of $\frac{12 rad}{1 min} * \frac{1 rev}{2\pi rad} * \frac{60 min}{1 hr}$

Tags: trigonometry

For some reason, this answer got marked as incorrect:

$\frac{60 min}{1 hr} = 1$

$\frac{12 rad}{1 min} * \frac{1 rev}{2\pi rad} = \frac{12 rad}{1 min} * \frac{\frac{12 rev}{2\pi}}{12rad} = \frac{6}{\pi} rev/min$

Can someone tell me what mistakes I made?

*Rev = Revolutions
*The answer should contain a unit.

Comment: Minutes is also a unit of plane angle, in which case $\frac{60\text{min}}{1\text{hr}}\ne1$

Comment: So what did I do incorrectly and what should be the correct answer? I don't know what to do with the 60 min/1 hr, since I thought they cancel out.

Comment: What is $1\text{rev}$? Is it the plane angle in one revolution i.e. $2\pi\text{rad}$?

Comment: 1 rev = 1 revolution.

Answer (score 1):

These could all be units of plane angle, not time, in which case, use the given conversions:

$1\text{ hour angle}=15^\circ\\60\text{ minutes}=1^\circ\\\pi\text{ rad}=180^\circ\\1\text{ rev}=360^\circ$

Your final answer should be a dimensionless constant.

Comment: The question specifies to include a unit though, so I don't get how it is dimensionless.

Comment: @Stallmp It could be a trick question and you may be required to say the answer has no units, or $\text{hour}$ and $\text{minute}$ could be units of time after all.

Comment: I believe it makes more sense that not all units are units of plane angle. The chapter is about angular and linear velocity, so rad/minute makes more sense. I still don't get the min/hour part (since they should cancel to 1 if that is the case).

Comment: Your answer is correct if they are indeed units of time.

Comment: Apparently the answer was 360/pi rev/min?? Can you explain this?

Comment: @Stallmp It should be $\frac{360}\pi\frac{\text{rev}}{\text{hr}}$ or $\frac6\pi\frac{\text{rev}}{\text{min}}$. Possibly the book is wrong

Comment: Exactly what I thought, thanks for the confirmation and the help.

Answer (score 1):

In a problem like this there are two steps:

- Do arithmetic with the numerals to determine the numeral part of the answer,
- Cancel units to determine the units part of the answer.

The arithemetic part gives
$$\frac{12 \times 1 \times 60}{1 \times 2\pi \times 1} = \frac{360}{\pi}
$$
For the units part, after cancelling radians and minutes what's left is $\frac{rev}{hr}$, leading to a final answer of
$$\frac{360}{\pi} \frac{rev}{hr}
$$

Comment: I got this too, but isn't this the same as 6/pi rev/min? Someone else said they are units of plane angle.

Comment: Whether or not they are the same is irrelevant, because in the problem that was presented to you, the units of "minutes" cancel out and the unit of hours do not.

Comment: Even when revolving at a constant rate, the *number* of revolutions that occur in one hour is not the same as the *number* of revolutions that occur in one minute, and so the expression of that rate in "revolutions per hour" is not the same as the expression in "revolutions per minute".